# Matches not found by pd.DataFrame.merge

Tags: pandas, merge, left-join

I've got a three `pd.DataFrames`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': {0: 2210, 1: 2210, 2: 2210, 3: 2210, 4: 2210, 5: 2210, 6: 2210, 7: 2210, 8: 2210, 9: 2210, 10: 2210, 11: 2210, 12: 2210, 13: 2210, 14: 2210, 15: 2210, 16: 2210, 17: 2210, 18: 2210, 19: 2210, 20: 2210, 21: 2210}, 'var2': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 1, 15: 2, 16: 1, 17: 2, 18: 1, 19: 2, 20: 1, 21: 2}, 'var3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0}, 'var4': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0}, 'var5': {0: '121160', 1: '20066', 2: ' 58621', 3: ' 201084', 4: ' 100180', 5: ' 74230', 6: ' 27789', 7: ' 66975', 8: ' 57410', 9: ' 49413', 10: ' 57112', 11: ' 19188', 12: ' 61366', 13: ' 27341', 14: ' 59859', 15: ' 173954', 16: ' 205651', 17: ' 54861', 18: ' 165809', 19: ' 60252', 20: ' 182156', 21: ' 82403'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': {349176: 2210, 349225: 2210, 349913: 2210, 350247: 2210, 350342: 2210, 350518: 2210}, 'var2': {349176: 2, 349225: 1, 349913: 1, 350247: 2, 350342: 1, 350518: 2}, 'var5': {349176: 58786.0, 349225: 37572.0, 349913: 103955.0, 350247: 19197.0, 350342: 14664.0, 350518: 75773.0}, 'var3': {349176: 19, 349225: 22, 349913: 56, 350247: 75, 350342: 80, 350518: 95}, 'var4': {349176: 8, 349225: 52, 349913: 42, 350247: 0, 350342: 50, 350518: 17}})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': {349175: 2210, 349224: 2210, 349912: 2210, 350246: 2210, 350341: 2210, 350517: 2210, 350521: 2210}, 'var2': {349175: 2, 349224: 1, 349912: 1, 350246: 2, 350341: 1, 350517: 2, 350521: 1}, 'var5': {349175: 19188.0, 349224: 205651.0, 349912: 59859.0, 350246: 27341.0, 350341: 165809.0, 350517: 19197.0, 350521: 61366.0}, 'var6': {349175: 19, 349224: 22, 349912: 56, 350246: 75, 350341: 80, 350517: 95, 350521: 95}, 'var7': {349175: 8, 349224: 52, 349912: 42, 350246: 0, 350341: 50, 350517: 17, 350521: 40}})
```

I need to stack `df1` and `df2` together, then join them by left join with `df3` based on multiple variables: `var1, var2, var5`.

So I wrote:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0, sort = False).merge(df3, how = 'left', on = ['var1', 'var2', 'var5'])
```

but it doesn't find all the matching rows. Changing the type to outer join we can observe there's is for example two rows with the same values of `var1, var2` and `var3` - rows 11th and 28th, but they haven't been joined:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0, sort = False).merge(df3, how = 'outer', on = ['var1', 'var2', 'var5'])
```

I'm struggling to find a reason for that behaviour. I thought maybe data types are different within joining columns, but no - they are the same. I'm relatively new to Pandas, so maybe I'm missing something obvious here? What is the reason for that (unexpected) behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': {0: 2210, 1: 2210, 2: 2210, 3: 2210, 4: 2210, 5: 2210, 6: 2210, 7: 2210, 8: 2210, 9: 2210, 10: 2210, 11: 2210, 12: 2210, 13: 2210, 14: 2210, 15: 2210, 16: 2210, 17: 2210, 18: 2210, 19: 2210, 20: 2210, 21: 2210}, 'var2': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 1, 15: 2, 16: 1, 17: 2, 18: 1, 19: 2, 20: 1, 21: 2}, 'var3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0}, 'var4': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0}, 'var5': {0: '121160', 1: '20066', 2: ' 58621', 3: ' 201084', 4: ' 100180', 5: ' 74230', 6: ' 27789', 7: ' 66975', 8: ' 57410', 9: ' 49413', 10: ' 57112', 11: ' 19188', 12: ' 61366', 13: ' 27341', 14: ' 59859', 15: ' 173954', 16: ' 205651', 17: ' 54861', 18: ' 165809', 19: ' 60252', 20: ' 182156', 21: ' 82403'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': {349176: 2210, 349225: 2210, 349913: 2210, 350247: 2210, 350342: 2210, 350518: 2210}, 'var2': {349176: 2, 349225: 1, 349913: 1, 350247: 2, 350342: 1, 350518: 2}, 'var5': {349176: 58786.0, 349225: 37572.0, 349913: 103955.0, 350247: 19197.0, 350342: 14664.0, 350518: 75773.0}, 'var3': {349176: 19, 349225: 22, 349913: 56, 350247: 75, 350342: 80, 350518: 95}, 'var4': {349176: 8, 349225: 52, 349913: 42, 350247: 0, 350342: 50, 350518: 17}})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': {349175: 2210, 349224: 2210, 349912: 2210, 350246: 2210, 350341: 2210, 350517: 2210, 350521: 2210}, 'var2': {349175: 2, 349224: 1, 349912: 1, 350246: 2, 350341: 1, 350517: 2, 350521: 1}, 'var5': {349175: 19188.0, 349224: 205651.0, 349912: 59859.0, 350246: 27341.0, 350341: 165809.0, 350517: 19197.0, 350521: 61366.0}, 'var6': {349175: 19, 349224: 22, 349912: 56, 350246: 75, 350341: 80, 350517: 95, 350521: 95}, 'var7': {349175: 8, 349224: 52, 349912: 42, 350246: 0, 350341: 50, 350517: 17, 350521: 40}})

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0).dtypes
```

results in

```
var1     int64
var2     int64
var3     int64
var4     int64
var5    object
dtype: object
```

As you can see after the concat the var5 is an object.  If you merge at this point you will get no results as var5 in df3 is a float.

Here is what I would recommend:

```py
df1['var5'] = df1['var5'].astype(float)
df2['var5'] = df2['var5'].astype(float)
df3['var5'] = df3['var5'].astype(float)
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0).merge(df3, how = 'left', on = ['var1', 'var2', 'var5'])
```

This will produce the following DataFrame:

```
    var1  var2  var3  var4      var5  var6  var7
0   2210     1     0     0  121160.0   NaN   NaN
1   2210     2     0     0   20066.0   NaN   NaN
2   2210     1     0     0   58621.0   NaN   NaN
3   2210     2     0     0  201084.0   NaN   NaN
4   2210     1     0     0  100180.0   NaN   NaN
5   2210     2     0     0   74230.0   NaN   NaN
6   2210     1     0     0   27789.0   NaN   NaN
7   2210     2     0     0   66975.0   NaN   NaN
8   2210     1     0     0   57410.0   NaN   NaN
9   2210     2     0     0   49413.0   NaN   NaN
10  2210     1     0     0   57112.0   NaN   NaN
11  2210     2     0     0   19188.0  19.0   8.0
12  2210     1     0     0   61366.0  95.0  40.0
13  2210     2     0     0   27341.0  75.0   0.0
14  2210     1     0     0   59859.0  56.0  42.0
15  2210     2     0     0  173954.0   NaN   NaN
16  2210     1     0     0  205651.0  22.0  52.0
17  2210     2     0     0   54861.0   NaN   NaN
18  2210     1     0     0  165809.0  80.0  50.0
19  2210     2     0     0   60252.0   NaN   NaN
20  2210     1     0     0  182156.0   NaN   NaN
21  2210     2     0     0   82403.0   NaN   NaN
22  2210     2    19     8   58786.0   NaN   NaN
23  2210     1    22    52   37572.0   NaN   NaN
24  2210     1    56    42  103955.0   NaN   NaN
25  2210     2    75     0   19197.0  95.0  17.0
26  2210     1    80    50   14664.0   NaN   NaN
27  2210     2    95    17   75773.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: The nature of `var5` is in fact categorical and its representation as float in `df3` must be some weird behaviour from `pd.DataFrame(df3.to_dict())` as `d3.dtypes` shows it as `object` before dumping it into `dict`. I have replaced your approach with converting to `int` and it did work. Explicit converting `var5` to `object` type in both data frames and joining them after didn't work though. It appears you can join if `var5` is `float` or `int`, but not an `object` - any idea why?

Comment: @jakes, Since you used my approach feel free to accept my answer :).  The datatypes int and float will not join, nor one of those to object.  When you concat the df1 and df2 the column becomes object because df1 is an object.  You can always convert int / floats to objects but not necessarily the opposite.  So Pandas is going to covert those to objects on concat.  If you concat float and ints you are going to get a float column.  To your question you could never join text to numeric.

Comment: I get it, but I'm still pondering why the following didn't worked: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0).astype({'var5': 'object'}).merge(df3.astype({'var5': 'object'}), how = 'left', on = ['var1', 'var2', 'var5'])`

Comment: @jakes  I understand what you are saying now.  When the floats convert to object the decimal remains. So string '19188.0' is not equal to the string '19188' if you wanted to convert to objects and then join you could do ```.astype({'var5':'int64'}).astype({'var5':'object'})```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code on my computer, then used `df#.dtypes` to get the types, the dtype of the `var5` column in `df1` is `object`, whereas in `df2` and `df3` it's `float64`. The concat runs fine with this (and after the concat, the dtype is `object`), but when I tried to run the merge (outer or left), I got a ValueError:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

I'd suggest double checking the types again (I know you already checked that). If they really are the same on your computer, I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I've checked once again, `var5` is an `object` in all initial data frames, as well as in the one resulting from `pd.concat()`.

Comment: Hmm maybe something was changed when you copied the dataframes into stackoverflow then... It does look like a float in df2 and df3: `'var5': {349176: 58786.0,`, `'var5': {349175: 19188.0,`. Can you verify that this is the same as what you have?